# What is a best way to find the number of days and months between two java.time.Instant objects?

Tags: java, java-time

*NOTE: search Google before marking this question as duplicate. I did search and browse this question and all answers that I found were either for LocalDate, Joda or legacy Java Date.*

*It took me quite some time to investigate this so I've decided to share this as an answer.*

I'd like a way to calculate the (approximate) number of months and days between two Java Instants (objects of java.time.Instant)?

Comment: I don't think the number of months between two instants has a widely accepted, well-defined, definition. Can you clarify exactly what are you trying to get?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, that's correct. However, this is something we have a need to calculate, as we use Instant internally and simply needed for the end-user to calculate a number of months and days (even approximate if not possible correct) between them. Ole V.V provided a way to calculate the accurate result in a given time zone.

Answer (score 1):

First, what you are asking is not well-defined. For example between the instants 2020-03-01T06:00:00Z and 2020-03-31T05:00:00Z could be:

- 29 days 23 hours in Australia/Melbourne time zone;
- 30 days in Europe/Paris time zone;
- 1 month 1 day in America/Los_Angeles time zone.

### Accurate result in a given time zone

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    Instant start = Instant.parse("2020-03-01T06:00:00Z");
    Instant end = Instant.parse("2020-03-31T05:00:00Z");
    ZonedDateTime startZdt = start.atZone(zone);
    LocalDate startDate = startZdt.toLocalDate();
    ZonedDateTime endZdt = end.atZone(zone);
    LocalDate endDate = endZdt.toLocalDate();
    Period p = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
    if (startZdt.plus(p).isAfter(endZdt)) {
        // The time of day on the end date is earlier, so don’t count a full date
        endDate = endDate.minusDays(1);
        p = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
    }
    System.out.println(p);
```

Output:

> P1M1D

Read as a period of 1 month 1 day.

### Approximate result independent of time zone

Prefer to leave as much of the calculation to java.time as possible. This includes the estimate of the length of a month.

```
    Duration diff = Duration.between(start, end);
    Duration durationOfAMonth = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.getDuration();
    long months = diff.dividedBy(durationOfAMonth);
    diff = diff.minus(durationOfAMonth.multipliedBy(months));
    long days = diff.toDays();

    System.out.println("" + months + " months " + days + " days");
```

> 0 months 29 days

Comment: The example at the start of your answer is exactly what I was trying to find but couldn't! I knew there has to be an example like that, but I just couldn't construct an example myself...

Answer (score 0):

I've opted out to approximate solution (it assumes all months have 30.44 days). I've opted out to use something like this:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(instant1, instant2).abs(); /* if want negative values remove .abs() */
long hours = duration.toHours();
double daysAndMonthsInDays = hours / 24.0;
int months = daysAndMonthsInDays / 30.44; //average number of days per month
int days = daysAndMonthsInDays - months * 30.44;
```

Please post another answer if there is a better solution using Duration class or something else. I've decided not to convert Instant to LocalDate and to perform the conversion on that level. That would not use an approximation of 30.44 days in a month, but rather the actual number.

Comment: it is awesome your asked question 13 minutes ago, and you found answer 13 minutes ago(as of now)

Comment: For the instants `2020-03-01T00:00:00Z` and `2020-12-01T00:00:00Z`, this gives the unexpected result of 9 months and _1 day_. Can you justify this result? I think it should output exactly 9 months.

Comment: ... there's `Duration.toDays()`, which would at least save you a step.  Otherwise, translating to `LocalDate` means you could then use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), which would give you the exact answer.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan answering your own question is both [allowed *and* encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: i never said it is not allowed